# What is the proper way to setup Searchkick with Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, searchkick

Just followed the searchkick official's docs to setup the tests, so that I can test my search controller:

Let's assume I have the following model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
searchkick

    def search_data
      {
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        email: email,
        emergency_contacts: build_emergency_contacts_data
      }
    end

    def build_emergency_contacts_data
      emergency_contacts.map do |contact|
        {
          id: contact.id,
          name: contact.name,
          email: contact.email,
        }
      end
    end

  has_many :emergency_contacts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The following controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def search
    response = User.search(params[:query])

    render json: response, status: :ok
  end
end
```

With that, I wrote the following test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSearchTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    Searchkick.enable_callbacks
  end

  def teardown
    Searchkick.disable_callbacks
  end

  test 'search users' do
    create(:user, :reindex)
    create(:user, :reindex, first_name: 'Jane', email: 'jane.doe@example.com')
    create(:user, :reindex, last_name: 'Smith', email: 'john.smith@example.com')

    get '/users/search', params: { query: 'john' }

    assert_response :success
    assert_equal 2, response.parsed_body["query"].size
  end
end
```

this is my users factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name { "John" }
    last_name { "Doe" }
    email { "john@example.com" }

    trait :reindex do
      after(:create) do |user, _evaluator|
        user.reindex(refresh: true)
      end
    end

    trait :with_emergency_contacts do
      after(:create) do |user, _evaluator|
        create_list(:emergency_contact, 2, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Running the previous test, I expect it to pass. But instead, I am getting the following error:

```
Error:
UsersSearchTest#test_search_users:
Searchkick::InvalidQueryError: Bad mapping - run User.reindex
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `search'
    test/integration/users_search_test.rb:29:in `block in <class:UsersSearchTest>'
```

Why to I need to rerun `User.reindex`, when my factory already does it?

With that Error, I did the following change:

```
test 'search users' do
    create(:user, :reindex)
    create(:user, :reindex, first_name: 'Jane', email: 'jane.doe@example.com')
    create(:user, :reindex, last_name: 'Smith', email: 'john.smith@example.com')

    User.reindex

    get '/users/search', params: { query: 'john' }

    assert_response :success
    assert_equal 2, response.parsed_body["query"].size
  end
```

Now the tests passes, but calling `User.reindex` after `create(:user, :reindex)` feels redundant. Also, the test becomes very slow:

> Running 1 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
> Run options: --seed 43504
>
> Running:
>
> .
>
> Finished in 4.227345s, 0.2366 runs/s, 0.4731 assertions/s.
> 1 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

My `test/test_helper` setup:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"

module ActiveSupport
  class TestCase
    include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

    # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
    parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

    User.reindex
    Searchkick.disable_callbacks

    # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
    # fixtures :all

    # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

    parallelize_setup do |worker|
      Searchkick.index_suffix = worker

      User.reindex
    
      Searchkick.disable_callbacks
    end
  end
end
```

What am I missing?